# How to transfer portion of image to another image, with reference to three points?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am doing a small project, where I need to extract out hair from an portrait image and then swap that hair image to head of another image. Basically, its a hair swap project. For this, I have:

1. Extracted hair portion
2. And used seamless cloning to place into head of another image. But its not gave me a lot different result than expected.

Here is the final Image:

Source of Hair

[image: Source of hair]

Extracted hair

[image: Extracted Hair]

Destination Image

[image: Destination Image]

After seamless cloning

[image: Seamless Cloned]

Since it does not give good result. I read the document (Section 3.5 hairstyle Editing)on

> Simulation of Face/Hairstyle Swapping in Photographs with Skin Texture
> Synthesis

Link [Link for above documentation](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-011-0891-1)

and got basic idea that, we can transfer hair portion using reference points.

But, I dont know whether we can transfer with help of reference points in opencv python. I can find out the coordinate points for transfer. There is no problem for that. I want to know the technique. I web surfed but, didnt found anything.

Desired result:

[image: Hair position reference points]

Using of reference of points must, scale, rotate and place at required destination.

Hope, I cleared my view and requirements.

## UPDATE:

The result of affine transformation, I tried before:

[image: Affine transform and then seamless cloning]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can calculate reference points in both images? The task is how to transform _hair_ image according to those references points?

Comment: Yes. That's right. Is there any way to fulfill my requirements in opencv python??

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html) is the documentation that describes the affine transformations. Use designated points from both images to create transformation matrix for [warpAffine](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#warpaffine) method. Apply this transformation to the *hair* image and then blend it with your *destination* image.

Comment: I have tried affine transformation once before. It made my final result so much distorted, worst than above final result. I thought it will not work at all without second try. :). I think, I have to try little harder this time. However, I got a question, do those two images need to be of same size?? Because, last time when I did affine transformation, I did in two images of different size, so I thought, size matters.

Comment: Please post your code for affine transformation. It will be easier to confirm where is the problem. My guess is that perhaps a simple three-points affine transformation is not enough and you should use more points but I'm not sure.